# Export artboards in multiple folder with Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, artboard

I have a PSD file with several artboards, is there a way to set a specific folder to export each one of them when export with the command `cmd + alt + maj + w` (or Export as)?

The key is that I cannot really modify any Photoshop system files since the software is provided by my company and IT policy is pretty strict...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: yes but let me ask you first. does your company allows you to run photoshop scripts? if yes then you can simply assign (cmd + alt + maj + w) hotkey to the script which we can provide :)

Comment: btw just for making default folder location I don't think you should go through script :D

Comment: Good luck scripting `Export As` command, Design Phoenix...

Comment: The company allows to run scripts. They cannot be added inside the Presets folder, so it is hard to make them native.

Mapping key to run a script is a good idea though. 

Here is the logic of the script: I have around 30 artboards, these artboards corresponds to formats for different team. I want to create a folder per team and export some artboards to the folders A, some to the folder B, etc. 

Do you think that would be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you may try to do is to use `Image Assets` Generator plugin (comes with Photoshop from CC2017 I think?). It works like this:

1. Enable it in `File > Generator > Image Assets` menu;
2. rename artboards you want to export to `subfolder/imagename.png`;
3. ah, that's all. The assets are exported automatically.

You can also add things like sizes to names (`subfolder/25% imagename.jpg`). More information can be found [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html).

[image]

Note that this will export the assets to subfolders in the root folder of your PSD. If you need to export every artboard to a completely different location, I believe your options are limited to writing your own image exporter script (may be difficult and time consuming) or having an additional simple script that would copy all the files to the needed locations after you run `Export As`.

Comment: You are my hero.